# sudo subl and desktop entry for sublime text launches different apps

Tags: command-line, unity, sublime-text

I have modified sublime text with themes and plugins on ubuntu 15.04 and this had to be done with sudo subl because with the unity launcher I had a permission error with package manager installation.

So I used sudo subl and I installed everything.

The issue is when I use unity launcher, the same old vanilla sublime text opens without any theme and when I use sudo subl in terminal I get the proper sublime text I intend to use.

However I want the unity launcher to launch the same application.

Also I saw the contents of "subl" in /usr/bin/subl its the same as those in sublime-text.desktop

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

The problem was that the packages were installed in .config/sublime-text-3 and the owner of the directory was root, so the desktop entry did not have access to it.

```
sudo chown -R username:username /home/username/.config/sublime-text-3
```

The above command solved it.